# Conditional ng-show

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to put a condition in the following:

```
<h3 ng-show="ctrl.loggedIn">
{{ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName + " " + ctrl.loggedInUser.LastName + " is logged in."}}
</h3>
```

that is if the **ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName** is **undefined** or **null** then it wouldn't print.

Click [here](https://github.com/FlyingNanobot/ShareIt) to visit the project on github.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. use `ng-if` to add conditions in DOM

```
<h3 ng-show="ctrl.loggedIn" ng-if="ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName">
    {{ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName + " " + ctrl.loggedInUser.LastName + " is logged in."}}
</h3>
```

Comment: still no change

Comment: I have added a link to the project on Github. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

h3 will only show if ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName have some value

```
<h3 ng-show="ctrl.loggedIn && ( ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName!=null || (ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName!='undefined')")>
{{ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName + " " + ctrl.loggedInUser.LastName + " is logged in."}}
</h3>
```

you can also do like

```
 <h3 ng-hide="!ctrl.loggedIn && (ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName==null || (ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName=='undefined')")>
    {{ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName + " " + ctrl.loggedInUser.LastName + " is logged in."}}
    </h3>
```

Comment: @Ray Satadal Try this

Comment: I have added a link to the project on Github. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show

```
<h3 ng-show="ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName!=undefined || ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName!=null">
{{ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName + " " + ctrl.loggedInUser.LastName + " is logged in."}}
</h3>
```

Comment: I have added a link to the project on Github. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-switch on="ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName == null || ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName == undefined || ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName == ''">
    <h3 ng-switch-when="true">Please log in.</h3>
    <h3 ng-switch-when="false">{{ctrl.loggedInUser.FirstName + " " + ctrl.loggedInUser.LastName + " is logged in."}}</h3>
</div>
```

this worked for me.
thanks all for the ideas.